# How to enable and disable perf_hook based on Flag

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

We have large code with lot of function called in  series . For performance improvement we want to measure the time between to specific point.

Step by step we want to make improvement. I was thinking of making user of `perf_hook`
Our best use case will be using as below , as per the lib

```
const { PerformanceObserver, performance } = require('perf_hooks');

const obs = new PerformanceObserver((items) => {
  console.log(items.getEntries()[0].duration);
  performance.clearMarks();
});

obs.observe({ type: 'measure' });
performance.measure('Start to Now');

performance.mark('A');
doSomeLongRunningProcess(() => {
  performance.measure('A to Now', 'A');

  performance.mark('B');
  performance.measure('A to B', 'A', 'B');
});
```

I looked and searched in lib as well as web , did not find any env variable to enable or disable the perf_hook, so enable and disable the code in PROD stage.

Answer (score 0):

playing around the code .

Just putting the declaration based on condition

```
let obs = null;
//ACTIVATE or DEACTIVATE
if( true || false) {
   obs = new PerformanceObserver((items) => {
              console.log(items.getEntries()[0].duration);
              performance.clearMarks();
    });
    obs.observe({ type: 'measure' });

}
```

Comment: more details at this link : https://blog.logrocket.com/experimental-node-js-testing-the-new-performance-hooks-31fcdd2a747e/